# Python memory block

Tags: python

I saw [this blog post](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/essential-python-interview-questions-du107ozr6#question-6) showing an interesting Python memory block behavior. I read through the explanation but still not sure.

```
def f(x,l=[]):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l) 

f(2)
f(3)
```

Prints

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

Why not these below? After finishing `f(2)` where does `l` get cached? I thought all the local variables would get wiped out.

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

All local variables *do* get wiped out, but the default value for `l` is not local to the function body but actually part of the function definition, initialized once when the function object is constructed.

So here, `l` serves as a "cache" of sorts, exploiting the mutability of lists.